# How to display 2nd last record using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

db table.

```
applicant
       app_id(p)   fullname 
        ------------------------------------
           1       John Bie 
           2       Hanna 


rec_list

       Id(p)   app_id(f)  fullname request
       ------------------------------------
        1         1       John Bie   ball
        2         1       John Bie   bag
        3         2       Hanna      Jewelry
        4         1       John Bie   tshirt
        5         2       Hanna      Dress
```

here's my query: it will show the last 2nd record of the app_id.

```
$app1 = $_GET["app_id"];
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rec_list WHERE app_id = $app1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1")
```

the result will show the 2nd record.

```
Name: John Bie
last request: Bag
```

but when I viewed the Bag in my preview.php script
the result still

```
Name: John Bie
last request: Bag
```

how to make it show like this: ball>bag>tshirt

```
Name: John Bie
last request: ball
```

Comment: show us what youve tried?

Comment: the record of John Die is. ball>bag>tshirt if you view tshirt it will show the last request: bag. but if you view bag it will show bag(it must be "ball"). how to get the previous record of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT columns FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

You can put your cuurent request value in `$curr_request` variable.
i.e when you view tshirt, `$curr_request` will be `tshirt`.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rec_list WHERE app_id = $app1 AND request != '$curr_request' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: thanks for sharing sir. I want to happen that the 3 records of app_id(1) john Die. if you view the 2nd record of app_id(1) john Die. it will show the 1st record. if you view the 3rd record it will show the 2nd record.

Comment: @kimdecastro whenever you view any request your query will be fired right?

Comment: yup sir. I display the records thru datables. the only problem I have is to get the last request. 1>2>3 if you click 3 it will get you last request: 2. if 2 it will get you last request: 1.

Comment: @kimdecastro After clicking on 3 set the `$curr_request = 3` and execute above query. Repeat same thing for other requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90381/discussion-between-rohit-gaikwad-and-kim-de-castro).